# Messages I sent

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

"The number of messages I sent yesterday was less than the messages I sent three days ago, and more than the messages I sent ten days ago."

**How many consecutive days can someone make this statement given that it is true?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not so many days.

> A total of 7 days to be exact.
>  Your number will have to be gradually smaller to stay smaller than 3 days ago, but when that first value of 3 days ago becomes the value of 10 days ago, it will be too high. 10-3 = 7 days.
> Example : 0-0-0-0-0-0-0-9-9-8-8(TODAY)-7-7-6-6-5-5.

**EDIT**:

> It is actually possible to get an 8th day by using a simple trick. 1 day ago and 3 days ago are odd, but 10 days ago is even, so by creating 2 chains, we can make it so the number from yesterday  be from a *high* chain and the the value from 10 days ago be from a *low* chain
>  Example : 0-0-0-0-0-0-0-9-19-8-18(TODAY)-7-17-6-16-5-15-4

Comment: There is just one thing you didn't consider, it will be right if you correct it.